# PowerPoint macro to change font colour on all slide incl groups

Tags: text, powerpoint

I have over a lot of PowerPoint presentations each with many slides and want to change all blue font to black font in all slides, leaving font that is any other colour unchanged.  A significant amount of font is in ‘groups’ so I am looking for the macro to change this font too.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution to this issue is not programmatic. If the presentation was built correctly, the font would be colored with a theme color. Updating the theme with a new color would change all instances immediately, no programming required.

Short of that, you would have to loop through every character in every shape that has text on every slide, testing the font color and changing it when you find blue.

You can use my description as a starting point for some serious Googling to figure out how to create such a macro. Here's a page with lots of good PowerPoint VBA info and samples: [Programming PowerPoint](http://www.pptfaq.com/#name_PROGRAMMING_POWERPOINT)